# html5 nav besides to nav

Tags: css, html

Here is my html codes

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Avrupa Networking</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<header id="container"></header>

<div id="main">

<header id="header">
                <section id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" /></section>
                <section id="search">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <select class="s1"> <option>Tüm Kategoriler</option>
                                    <option>BAYAN ATLET/BODY/BÜSTİYER</option>
                                    <option>BAYAN ÇORAP</option>
                                    <option>BAYAN KÜLOT/BOXER</option>
                                    <option>BAYAN PİJAMA/EV GİYİM</option>
                                    <option>BAYAN TAYT</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="t1" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" class="b1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </section>
</header>

<nav id="lnav"></nav>

<nav id="mnav"> </nav>

</div>
<footer id="foot">

</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  
    background-color: #eceeed;  
    font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #4e5452;
}

.t1 {
    font-family:inherit;
    margin-left:3px;
    padding-left:5px;
    height: 30px; 
    width: 260px;   
    border: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
    outline:0px;
}
.s1 {
    font-family:inherit;
    margin-left: 2px;
    height: 40px; 
    width: 190px;     
    border: 0 !important;  
    -webkit-appearance: none;  
    -moz-appearance: none;  
    background: url('../images/select.png') no-repeat; 
    background-position: 170px 12px;  
    width: 190px; 
    text-indent: 0.01px; 
    text-overflow: "";  
}

.b1{
border:0px;
width:40px;
height:40px;
background-image: url(../images/search-button.jpg);
}
#container {
    background-image: url(../images/bg-horizonal-bar.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
}

#header {
    height:140px;
    width: 1000px auto;
    clear:both;
    }

#logo{
    float:left;
}

#search{
    width:500px;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:50px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;    
    border: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
    outline: 0;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 2, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE 1px, #FFFFFF 2px);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 0 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 0 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 0 5px;
}

#main{
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

#lnav{
    width:200px;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #c40100;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

#mnav{
    margin-left:10px;
    height:45px;
    width: 790px;
    background-color:#000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #c40100;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;


}
```

[Problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJsJC.jpg)
nav items dont align horizantally, i've tried float left to left left to right just nothing
i tried some clear codes and changes nav to div 
did i use wrong html5
or is it only CSS
What CSS codes for lnav and mnav?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tjybnuch/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tjybnuch/1/) or [Fiddle SHOW](http://jsfiddle.net/tjybnuch/1/show/)

**Solution 2:** use `float: right;` to `#mnav` and `float: left;` to `#lnav` - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tjybnuch/2/)** or **[SHOW](http://jsfiddle.net/tjybnuch/2/show/)**

You could use `float: left;` to `#mnav` and `#lnav` and you've fixed `width: 1000px;` to your `#main` container then using `float` is a good option for you.

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px;  
    background-color: #eceeed;  
    font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #4e5452;
}
.t1 {
    font-family:inherit;
    margin-left:3px;
    padding-left:5px;
    height: 30px; 
    width: 260px;   
    border: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
    outline:0px;
}
.s1 {
    font-family:inherit;
    margin-left: 2px;
    height: 40px; 
    width: 190px;     
    border: 0 !important;  
    -webkit-appearance: none;  
    -moz-appearance: none;  
    background: url('../images/select.png') no-repeat; 
    background-position: 170px 12px;  
    width: 190px; 
    text-indent: 0.01px; 
    text-overflow: "";  
}
.b1 {
border:0px;
width:40px;
height:40px;
background-image: url(../images/search-button.jpg);
}
#container {
    background-image: url(../images/bg-horizonal-bar.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
}
#header {
    height:140px;
    width: 1000px auto;
    clear:both;
    }
#logo {
    float:left;
}
#search {
    width:500px;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:50px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow:hidden;    
    border: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
    outline: 0;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 2, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #EEEEEE), to(#FFFFFF));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EEEEEE 1px, #FFFFFF 2px);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 0 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 0 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 0 5px;
}
#main {
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
#lnav {
    width:200px;
    height:45px;
    float: left;
    background-color:#000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #c40100;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
#mnav {
    float: left;
    margin-left:10px;
    height:45px;
    width: 790px;
    background-color:#000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #c40100;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<header id="container"></header>
<div id="main">
    <header id="header">
        <section id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" />
        </section>
        <section id="search">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select class="s1">
                            <option>Tüm Kategoriler</option>
                            <option>BAYAN ATLET/BODY/BÜSTİYER</option>
                            <option>BAYAN ÇORAP</option>
                            <option>BAYAN KÜLOT/BOXER</option>
                            <option>BAYAN PİJAMA/EV GİYİM</option>
                            <option>BAYAN TAYT</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="t1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="b1" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>
    </header>
    <nav id="lnav"></nav>
    <nav id="mnav"></nav>
</div>
<footer id="foot"></footer>
```

Comment: but my fiddle is working fine, right? or you want your nav's to look like that image?

Comment: @OuuzzOuuzz It's working fine for me too... There is no mistake with this code. It may be a cookies problem. So clear history in your browser and check it again.

Comment: @Mary Melody there is no change :/

Comment: @OuuzzOuuzz I've noticed one error in your css code - `#header {width: 1000px auto;}` that's invalid you should use `#header {width: 1000px;}` TRY - http://jsfiddle.net/tjybnuch/3/show or http://jsfiddle.net/tjybnuch/3/

Comment: @Mary Melody i exactly copied codes you gave i tried to clear cache. Still same. Should i burn my pc and buy a new one :D

Comment: i think one thing left to do. i edited positioning main -> relative and navs -> absolute  left right 0px its done :)

Comment: @OuuzzOuuzz OK... if its done then you could accept my answer... lol :)

Answer (score 0):

Make  `#lnav` ,  `#mnav` as `'display:inline-block'` so Right nav will get a space to fit and reduce the width of right nav go fit in.

Here is the demo using display:inline-block and reducing the right nav width http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/kyfztxht/2/

**CSS**

```
#lnav{
width: 200px;
height: 45px;
background-color: #000;
border-bottom: 5px solid #c40100;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
display: inline-block;
}

#mnav {
margin-left: 10px;
height: 45px;
width: 770px;
background-color: #000;
border-bottom: 5px solid #c40100;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Or else `float the navigation` and wrap them inside a div like this and use `clearfix`

Here is link using floats http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/p717orum/

```
<div class="navigation cf">
   <nav id="lnav"></nav>

   <nav id="mnav"> </nav>

 </div>
```

Clearfix code put it in css

```
.cf:after,
.cf:before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
.cf {
    zoom: 1;
}
#lnav{
width: 200px;
height: 45px;
background-color: #000;
border-bottom: 5px solid #c40100;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
float:left;
}

#mnav {
margin-left: 10px;
height: 45px;
width: 770px;
background-color: #000;
border-bottom: 5px solid #c40100;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
float:right
}
```

When ever you float the elements use clearfix code to avoid conflicts and add 'cf' class to the floated elements parents. Like i have added 'cf' class to the nav parent i.e 'navigation'.

I Hope it helps You in future.